# @Transactional rollback session.save() on exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, oracle12c

I've been testing rollbacks with the `@Transactional` annotation. If an unchecked exception is thrown, `session` operations should be rolled back.

I am using `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect`.

I have `@EnableTransactionManagement` enabled.

In this first example, `entity` already exists in the database. I am updating it's name from "Test" to "Test123". After `session.saveOrUpdate()` is called, a `RuntimeException` is thrown. Checking the database after the fact, the update did not go through.

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
@RestController
@Transactional
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value = "")
    public String test() {
        
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
        entity.setId(123); // Update existing
        entity.setName("Test123");
        entity.setCreateUser("user1");
        entity.setUpdateUser("user1");

        session.saveOrUpdate(entity);

        throw new RuntimeException("Test");
    }
}
```

In the second example, `entity` does not yet exist in the database. After calling `session.saveOrUpdate()` a `RuntimeException()` is thrown again. When checking the database, the new record was created.

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
@RestController
@Transactional
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value = "")
    public String test() {
        
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
        entity.setId(null); // Create new 
        entity.setName("TestNew");
        entity.setCreateUser("user1");
        entity.setUpdateUser("user1");

        session.saveOrUpdate(entity);

        throw new RuntimeException("Test");
    }
}
```

One interesting thing I found is, in the first example, hibernate does not print out any SQL in the console. In the second example though, the insert statement is printed in the console before the exception is thrown. Does this make a difference?

In this final example, I wrap my statements in a manual transaction. Similar to the second example, `entity` does not exist in the database. We are creating a new instance. Within the transaction I throw a `RuntimeException()`
this exception gets caught and the transaction is rolled back successfully. The new record is not in the database.

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
@RestController
@Transactional
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value = "")
    public String test() {
        
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
            entity.setId(null); // Create new 
            entity.setName("TestNew2");
            entity.setCreateUser("user1");
            entity.setUpdateUser("user1");

            session.saveOrUpdate(entity);

            throw new RuntimeException("Test");
            
            tx.commit();
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does example two not rollback? But example three does successfully rollback?

Edit: I am also using Hikari CP. Which has `auto-commit` set to `true`. I'm not sure if that effects anything. But when I set that to `false`, I at least then don't see the change in the database. But I believe that is because I would need to do manual transactions at that point.

Also here are the logs incase there is anything helpful in there:

```
2021-02-21 10:44:42.604 DEBUG VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2021-02-21 10:44:42.650 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@68d89998] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@367628c8] to thread [http-nio-8081-exec-1]
2021-02-21 10:44:42.659 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@68d89998] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@367628c8] bound to thread [http-nio-8081-exec-1]
2021-02-21 10:44:42.659 DEBUG VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@393e2dcf] for JPA transaction
2021-02-21 10:44:42.659 DEBUG VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Creating new transaction with name [com.package.myentity.web.PingService.createOrUpdate]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2021-02-21 10:44:42.709 DEBUG VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@77af7c9c]
2021-02-21 10:44:42.709 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@77b95111] for key [HikariDataSource (My WS)] to thread [http-nio-8081-exec-1]
2021-02-21 10:44:42.709 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
2021-02-21 10:44:42.710 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.package.myentity.web.PingService.createOrUpdate]
2021-02-21 10:44:42.713 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@4a056888] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@4639d92c] to thread [http-nio-8081-exec-1]
2021-02-21 10:36:25.781 DEBUG VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.h.SQL                                  : 
    insert 
    into
        dev_schema.my_entity
        (id, name, create_user, update_user) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
44:42.935 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.package.myentity.web.PingService.createOrUpdate] after exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
2021-02-21 10:44:42.935 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.RuntimeException
2021-02-21 10:44:42.935 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : Winning rollback rule is: null
2021-02-21 10:44:42.935 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
2021-02-21 10:44:42.935 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
2021-02-21 10:44:42.935 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@4a056888] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@4639d92c] from thread [http-nio-8081-exec-1]
2021-02-21 10:44:42.935 DEBUG VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Initiating transaction rollback
2021-02-21 10:44:42.935 DEBUG VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@393e2dcf]
2021-02-21 10:44:42.986 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
2021-02-21 10:44:42.986 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
2021-02-21 10:44:42.988 TRACE VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@77b95111] for key [HikariDataSource (My WS)] from thread [http-nio-8081-exec-1]
2021-02-21 10:44:42.988 DEBUG VT0718LA899 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
java.lang.RuntimeException

...
```

Comment: Can you add `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` and check if there is any change in behaviour?

Comment: @JavaLearner there were a couple of new entries in the log. But no change in the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well, auto-commit means that after every statement, the transaction is committed and a new one is started. The insert statement does not fail, so this is committed then. The update statement fails though, which is why the transaction is rolled back and you are not seeing the change. Always disable auto-commit.

Comment: The OP had `@Transactional` annotation on Controller class. Will it still be in autocommit mode for example 2 above?

Comment: @Christian Beikov The SQL never gets executed for the update. Or at least it is not output in the console. I assume that is because updates don't actually execute until a ```session.flush()```? Where as a ```save``` executes immediately? But even then, I don't understand why the ```save``` isn't rolling back on a Runtime exception.

Comment: I don't think `@Transactional` tries to normalize the auto-commit flag, but not sure. Apart from that, why is the OP messing with transactions then if this is already using `@Transactional`. I think something is just misconfigured in that app. Regarding the flush of the update, you are probably right, the update is deferred until flush, which happens right before commit. You can flush manually though to maybe see the issue earlier. Spring also allows to configure on which exceptions to rollback. Anyway, did you try disabling auto-commit already?

Comment: @ChristianBeikov messing with manual transactions was a hack for working around the fact that ```@Transactional``` wasn't rolling back ```session.save()```. Obviously it is not the preferred solution. I would love to know what I can check for misconfiguration. Because if that ended up being the case, that would save a lot of headache. Again I've seen most examples online show ```session.save()``` rolling back fine with the ```@Transactional``` annotation. I have not yet tried disabling auto-commit. It is definitely one of the next options I will look into.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov if I set ```spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false```, then ```session.save()``` does not automatically persist. I need to call ```session.beginTransaction()``` and ```session.getTransaction().commit()``` in order for the insert to persist. Like you were saying though, where I am using ```@Transactional```, I shouldn't have to be messing with creating my own transactions.

Comment: Well, in that case there is something messed up with the transaction integration with Spring. I don't know how you setup your transaction manager or entity manager factory, but you should report your issue to the Spring team.